# Is it possible to do the gamma filter on a image in R?

Tags: r, image, filtering

I have a time series of SAR images, which I want to classify in R. But before I can use the data, I need to do the filtering. The most suitable filter is GAMMA for my data. So I am wondering if it is possible to do the GAMMA filtering in R, any available code for that? So that I don't need to do it in any other software?

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to have a look at the Bioconductor package **[EBImage](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/EBImage/)**, which provides general purpose functionality for image processing and analysis in *R*. To install the package use:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("EBImage")
```

In particular, the section on [manipulating images](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/EBImage-introduction.html#manipulating-images) in the package [vignette](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/EBImage-introduction.html) might be of interest to you. As described there, gamma filtering of an image is simply performed by exponentiation. This is illustrated in the following example.

```
library("EBImage")

## load a sample image file
f = system.file("images", "sample.png", package="EBImage")
img = readImage(f)
display(img)

## perform gamma correction
gamma_corrected = img ^ .5
display(gamma_corrected)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I am not sure if I completely understand you.  By doing gamma filtering, I am persuing an adaptive filtering to remove the speckes in  my grey images. But I have the impression that the gamma correction is somewhat image enhancement but not noise removal. forgive me if  I am wrong, I am kind of new in this field.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the type of adaptive gamma filter you describe, could you please provide some reference? For speckle noise removal you could also try the EBImage function `medianFilter` (see the package vignette for an example).